# Группировка объектов по времени

Tags: java, алгоритм

Сгруппировать объекты `Item` из листа `items` в список объектов `Group`, каждая группа хранит данные относящиеся к одной минуте.

Данные `value` внутри группы должны быть сгруппированы как среднеарифметические значения для заданного интервала в секундах. Если данных для текущего интервала N в исходном листе нет, то дублируется значение предыдущего интервала. Если данных не хватает для первого интервала в группе то дублируется последний интервал предыдущей группы.

Интервал всегда меньше или равен 60 сек. и делит минуту на равное число секунд без остатка.

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String time;
    private double value;
    // Getters, setters, constructors...
}
public class Group {
    private int id;
    private List<Item> items;
    // Getters, setters, constructors...
}
```

При длительности интервале = 30 для исходного списка:

```
List<Item> items = List.of(
        new Item(1, "19/09/2020 1:03:00 AM", 1.0),
        new Item(2, "19/09/2020 1:03:03 AM", 1.3),
        new Item(3, "19/09/2020 1:03:15 AM", 1.1),
        new Item(4, "19/09/2020 1:03:47 AM", 1.2),
        new Item(5, "19/09/2020 1:03:57 AM", 1.6),
        new Item(6, "19/09/2020 1:04:04 AM", 1.8),
        new Item(7, "19/09/2020 1:04:43 AM", 1.9),
        new Item(8, "19/09/2020 1:04:44 AM", 2.1),
        new Item(9, "19/09/2020 1:05:30 AM", 1.8),
        new Item(10, "19/09/2020 1:05:46 AM", 2.3)
);
```

Должно получиться:

```
List.of(
        new Group(1, List.of(
                new Item(1, "19/09/2020 1:03:00 AM", 1.13), // первые 30 сек value = (1.0 + 1.3 + 1.1) / 3
                new Item(2, "19/09/2020 1:03:30 AM", 1.4) // вторые 30 сек value = (1.2 + 1.6) / 2
        )),
        new Group(2, List.of(
                new Item(1, "19/09/2020 1:04:00 AM", 1.8), // первые 30 сек
                new Item(2, "19/09/2020 1:04:30 AM", 1.5) // вторые 30 сек
        )),
        new Group(2, List.of(
                new Item(1, "19/09/2020 1:05:00 AM", 1.5), // для первых 30 сек данных нет, в результат пойдет предыдущее значение
                new Item(2, "19/09/2020 1:05:30 AM", 2.05) // вторые 30 сек
        )));
```

Сигнатура `List<Group> transform(List<Item> src, int intervalSize)`

Все что мне пока удалось это только создать пустой список групп

```
public class Transformer {

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

    @SneakyThrows
    public List<Group> transform(List<Item> source, int intervalSize) {
        List<Group> target = getEmptyGroups(source);

        return target;
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private List<Group> getEmptyGroups(List<Item> source) {
        Item start = source.get(0);
        Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        startTime.setTime(formatter.parse(start.getTime()));
        Item end = source.get(source.size() - 1);
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.setTime(formatter.parse(end.getTime()));
        long groupTotal = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(startTime.toInstant(), endTime.toInstant()) + 1;
        List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < groupTotal, i -> i + 1)
                .forEachOrdered(i -> {
                    Group group = new Group();
                    group.setId(i + 1);
                    groups.add(group);
                });
        return groups;
    }
}
```

Comment: Откуда этот синтаксис `List.of` ? :)  "Если данных для текущего интервала N нет", если я правильно понял,  нужно сначала определиться что выводить: Предыдущую или следующую группу?

Comment: @Vitaliy M.V да, если это первая запись в группе и данных для нее нет, то записываем последний интервал предыдущей. А про List.of не понял это просто для сокращения

Comment: "записываем последний интервал предыдущей" - что вы подразумеваете под интервалом? Группу объектов `Item` типа `List<Item> items = List.of( .... );` ?

Comment: @Vitaliy M.V да, есть Group с листом Item внутри, нам надо подсчитать 1й Item группы но данных для него нет, тогда мы берем последний Item предыдущей Group и дублируем его value для заполнения 1го новой Item группы. Если intervalSize = 30 то в каждой группе будет по 2 Item, раз данных для первых 30 сек нет то мы заполняем последним известным значением. Интервал - это интервал времени на пример 30 сек. значит внутри каждого Item будет среднеарифметическая за 30 сек. и в группу их поместится 2шт

Comment: Я смутно понимаю задачу. Не знаю чем вам помочь. Попробуйте поставить свой вопрос иначе.

Comment: @Vitaliy M.V есть список где на против времени лежит значение, нужно сначала сгруппировать по данные по минутам, Group в нем лежат только данные относящиеся к одной минуте(12:00:01, 12:00:40...), и еще один в котором данные которые относятся ко второй (12:01:12, 12:01:21) и так далее... А потом внутри самой группы то что мы туда отфильтровали смапить в фиксированный список Item в зависимости от длинны интервала если интервал 20 сек то в минуту их поместится 3 шт. нужно из имеющихся данных заполнить эти Item новыми среднеарифметическими значениями. Так лучше?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139309/discussion-between-pavel-and-vitaliy-m-v).

Comment: Стримы здесь не слишком подходят, так как существует зависимость между разными группами/интервалами, когда должно использоваться _предыдущее_ значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего, у вас что-то не так с ожидаемыми значениями.
У объекта 2.2 метка времени  `"19/09/2020 1:04:00 AM"`, а должно быть  `"19/09/2020 1:04:30 AM"`, не так ли? Аналогично для объекта 3.2. Кстати, у последней группы номер должен быть 3, а не 2, правильно?

Непонятно среднее значение для объекта 2.2. У вас `1.5`, но должно быть `(1.9+2.1)/2 -> 2.0`.

Теперь о решении.

Если решать по-простому, в лоб, без оптимизации по памяти, то я бы делал вот как.

Разбить период на непересекающиеся окна. Например, в вашем случае период 60 секунд разбит на два окна. Далее в бесконечном цикле - если объект принадлежит текущему интервалу, то добавить его в соответствующее окно, в противном случае закрыть интервал и начать следующий, до тех пор пока объект не окажется внутри интервала.

Закрыть окно означает сделать `Item` с меткой времени, соответствующей началу окна, и значением равным среднему значению за время окна.

Код для окна.

```
package org.example.groups;


import java.text.ParseException;

public class Window {
    public static final long PERIOD = 60000;
    
    public final int windowId;
    public long start;
    public long end;
    public int count = 0;
    public double sum = 0.0;
    public double lastValue = 0.0;
    
    public Window(long start, long duration, int windowId) {
        this.windowId = windowId;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = start + duration;
    }
    
    public double add(double v) throws ParseException {
        count +=1;
        sum += v;
        return value();
    }
    
    public double value() {
        if (count == 0) {
            return lastValue;
        }
        return sum / count;
    }
    
    public Item shift()  {
        return shift(1);
    }
    
    public Item shift(int n) {
        Item result = toItem();
        
        lastValue = value();        
        sum = 0.0;
        count = 0;
        start += n*PERIOD;
        end += n*PERIOD;
        
        return result;
    }
    
    public Item toItem() {
        return new Item(
                windowId,
                Util.toDateString(start),
                value()
                );
    }
    
    public boolean isIn(long t) throws ParseException {
        return (start <= t && t < end); 
    }
}
```

Код для подсчета средних значений:

```
package org.example.groups;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Average {
    public List<Item> items;

    private Window[] windows;
    private double lastValue = 0.0;

    private final long duration;

    public Average(long start, int numOfWindows) {
        items = new LinkedList<Item>();
        long intervalStart = Util.periodStart(start);
        long intervalEnd = intervalStart + Window.PERIOD;
        
        duration = Window.PERIOD / numOfWindows;
        windows = new Window[numOfWindows];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWindows; i++) {
            windows[i] = new Window(intervalStart + duration*i, duration, i+1);
        }
        windows[numOfWindows-1].end = intervalEnd;
    }
    
    private long intervalStart() {
        return windows[0].start;
    }
    
    private long intervalEnd() {
        return intervalStart() + Window.PERIOD;
    }

    private boolean isIn(long t) {
        return (intervalStart() <= t && t < intervalEnd());
    }

    private void finishPeriod() {
        for (Window w : windows) {
            w.lastValue = lastValue;
            Item it = w.shift();
            lastValue = it.getValue();
            items.add(it);
        }
    }

    public void add(Item it) throws ParseException {
        long t = Util.timeInMillis(it);
        while (!isIn(t)) {
            finishPeriod();
        }
        int wIdx = (int) ((t - intervalStart()) / duration);
        assert(wIdx < windows.length);
        windows[wIdx].add(it.getValue());
    }
    
    public List<Item> finish() {
        finishPeriod();
        return items;
    }
    
    public List<Group> groupify() {
        LinkedList<Group> result = new LinkedList<Group>();
        
        int itemsPerGroup = windows.length;
        int groupId = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i+=itemsPerGroup) {
            Group g = new Group(groupId++, items.subList(i, i+itemsPerGroup));
            result.add(g);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Класс `Average` параметризуется началом интервала и числом окошек внутри периода. Длительность периода задана константой `Window.PERIOD` в миллисекундах. Метод `public void add(Item it)` сдвигает интервал при необходимости и затем добавляет объект в соответствующее окно. При сдвиге интервала средние значения добавляются в список `items`.

Для простоты я пишу объекты в список сплошняком и только при необходимости собираю в группы, но можно было бы собирать группы внутри `finishPeriod`.

В чём это решение неоптимально.

1. Можно было бы обойтись одним окном, которое скользит внутри интервала.
2. В том случае, когда в данных большие просветы между отметками времени, можно было бы не сохранять "пустые" `Item`, а только для тех интервалов, в которых были данные.

Полный код: https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/tree/main/java/1450111

Пример запуска для двух интервалов в периоде:

```
package org.example.groups;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        List<Item> items = List.of(
                new Item(1, "19/09/2020 1:03:00 AM", 1.0),
                new Item(2, "19/09/2020 1:03:03 AM", 1.3),
                new Item(3, "19/09/2020 1:03:15 AM", 1.1),
                new Item(4, "19/09/2020 1:03:47 AM", 1.2),
                new Item(5, "19/09/2020 1:03:57 AM", 1.6),
                new Item(6, "19/09/2020 1:04:04 AM", 1.8),
                new Item(7, "19/09/2020 1:04:43 AM", 1.9),
                new Item(8, "19/09/2020 1:04:44 AM", 2.1),
                new Item(9, "19/09/2020 1:05:30 AM", 1.8),
                new Item(10, "19/09/2020 1:05:46 AM", 2.3)
        );
        long start = Util.timeInMillis(items.get(0));
        start = Util.periodStart(start);
        
        Average av = new Average(start, 2);

        for (Item it : items) {
            av.add(it);
        }
        av.finish()
    
        for (Group g : av.groupify()) {
            System.out.println(g.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Group [id=1, items=[Item [id=1, time=Sat Sep 19 01:03:00 KST 2020, value=1.13], Item [id=2, time=Sat Sep 19 01:03:30 KST 2020, value=1.40]]]
Group [id=2, items=[Item [id=1, time=Sat Sep 19 01:04:00 KST 2020, value=1.80], Item [id=2, time=Sat Sep 19 01:04:30 KST 2020, value=2.00]]]
Group [id=3, items=[Item [id=1, time=Sat Sep 19 01:05:00 KST 2020, value=2.00], Item [id=2, time=Sat Sep 19 01:05:30 KST 2020, value=2.05]]]
```

Comment: да по ожидаемым значением вы правы. Исправил